# How to remove the row that has special characters in it

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a large text file that has a lot of special characters in it like "$!@%#$/" plus many more and I would like to remove the line in the text file if it has any special characters in that line. The only characters I want to keep is a-z and A-Z.

If this was the file...

```
!Somejunk)(^%
)%(&_
this
my_file
is
*(%%$
the
they're
file
```

Then the only thing that would be left would be...

```
this
is
the
file
```

A solution with linux command line tools, or a bash script, or a python script would be better, but anything that works will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep ONLY lines with alpha characters (as the OP requested), then:

```
$ grep -v '[^a-zA-Z]' foo
```

Or if you only want *English* characters:

```
$ grep -v '[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]' foo
```

But if you just want to remove non-alpha characters, `sed` will do the job:

```
$ cat foo | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'
```

Or if you just want to kill *binary*, non-printable data, use strings:

```
$ strings foo
```

Comment: The sed command would only make the unwanted lines blank. To prevent printing the them you'd need to tell sed when to print; `sed -n '/^[a-zA-Z]\+$/p'`. This is equivalent to the grep though, and probably slower.

Comment: which one does what you want?

Comment: Well I thought the grep did. But I just looked at the file really close and found ëöü characters still in it...

Comment: accented latin characters probably fall within the a-z range, so if you only want *english* characters try:
$ grep -v '[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]' foo

Comment: I ran the `strings filename` command after the grep command and that worked as well. Thank-you for your help! It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

```
$ grep '^[[:alpha:]]\+$' << EOF
> !Somejunk)(^%
> )%(&_
> this
> my_file
> is
> *(%%$
> the
> they're
> file
> EOF
this
is
the
file
```

Comment: Or `grep -v '[^[:alpha:]]'`, which is even shorter.

Comment: The regex is shorter, but the command itself is the same length.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
 sed '/[^[:alpha:]]/d' source_file
```

Comment: If I could up-vote I would because this also works. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

`grep -v` and some regex?

say,
`egrep -v '[^a-zA-Z]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to filter out the required lines:

grep '^[A-Za-z ]\+$' *file*

If you don't even allow spaces in rows, you may omit out space after *z*.

Answer (score 0):

or like this completely in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(cat file.txt);

for line in $file; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take the really nooby approach.

```
x = open('file','r')
y = x.read().split('\n')
x.close()

for z in range (0, len(y)):
    for a in range (0, len(y[z])):
        if not y[z][a].isalpha() and not y[z][a].isdigit():
            y[z][a] = ''

OutputString = '\n'.join(y)
```